# Comparação de dias (maior e menor)

Tags: php

Achei algo parecido aqui mas ainda não é o que quero.
Tenho o seguinte código em php:

```
$data_t2 = date('dmY', strtotime($inicio_provas));
$data_t3 = date('dmY', strtotime("+120 days"));
  if ($data_t2 < $data_t3) {
     $data_libera = "Você não pode marcar a Prova";
  }else{
     $data_libera = "Vai rolar meu amigo";
  }
```

Só que o que acontece... Ele está checando se é maior ou menor somente pelo dia, exemplo de dois resultados:

> "T2= 24102016" > "T3= 22022017" -> Vai rolar meu amigo
>
> "T2= 13102016" > "T3 = 22022017" -> Você não pode marcar a Prova

Sei lá, mas não entendi o pq ele só está julgando o dia e não o numero pro completo...

Comment: Você deve usar strotime em ambas variáveis.

Comment: @MauroAlexandre Eu esqueci de acrescentar, mas estou usando no código original, já editei... mas continua a minha dúvida...

Comment: Qual o valor de $inicio_provas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve fazer algo como

```
 $data1 = '2013-05-21';
 $data2 = '2013-05-22';

 if(strtotime($data1) > strtotime($data2)){
  echo 'A data 1 é maior que a data 2.';
 }elseif(strtotime($data1) == strtotime($data2)){
  echo 'A data 1 é igual a data 2.';
 }else{
  echo 'A data 1 é menor que a data 2.';
 }
```

Por favor, verifique que você está comparando de modo errado as variáveis.  Faça do modo que indiquei.

Comment: Comparando com o seu código, vi que o que estava complicando a minha vida era o formato "dmY"... Vlw man!